# Output from video recording with AVFoundation

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, video, avfoundation

I am recording a video using AVFoundation. I am using below code.

```
  -(IBAction)record:(id)sender
    {


     AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
     [session setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh];
      AVCaptureDevice *inputDevice = [AVCaptureDevice    defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

      NSError *error;

     AVCaptureDeviceInput *deviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:inputDevice error:&error];
     if ( [session canAddInput:deviceInput] )
     [session addInput:deviceInput];
     AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
    [previewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];

    CALayer *rootLayer = [[self view] layer];
    [rootLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [previewLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(-70, 0, rootLayer.bounds.size.height, rootLayer.bounds.size.height)];
    [rootLayer insertSublayer:previewLayer atIndex:0];

    [session startRunning];

 }
```

I can see the video on my previewlayer, how can I make this to NSData, so that I can send this to server instantaneously while recording for live broadcast.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` and connect it to your session, and then implement

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
```

Inside here `sampleBuffer` holds the data of the frame

Again, I recommend you look at RosyWriter sample App as it has an example of getting the data of the frame in pixels